# Accessing a network within my network?

Tags: networking, router, dhcp

I have a main network with a router (R1) distributing IPs using DHCP (192.168.100.X).
One of the IP (192.168.100.249) is used by another router (R2 - dedicated to kids usage and with parental control).
This second router R2 distributes IPs using DHCP (192.168.1.X).
I can connect the router R2 using its own wifi, no issue.
I would love to access the R2 network by connecting the wifi of R1 (having a better wifi range) : is it possible or completely impossible ?
Many thanks for any help !

Comment: Difficult to tell the topology from your description, but if these are your average home routers, then probably not since they do not allow you to setup routes on the lan side.

Comment: I think many home routers (though not all) allows you add static route that uses a LAN host (in this case `192.168.100.249`) as the gateway for certain destination (in this case `192.168.1.0/24`). Even if `R1` does not allow that, you can add the route on each of its LAN hosts (that you want to have such access on) *itself*. The problem is really whether the firewall on R2, if any, block traffics from its WAN side that has destination address of its LAN (or even any private IP). Some, *but not all*, NAT implementation might mess things up as well.

Comment: Disable NAT on R2 and setup a static route to 192.168.1.0/24 using 192.168.100.249 as the next hop. The static route may be supported on R1 or you may have to add it directly to each PC connected to the R1 network that you want to access the R2 network. Please note that everything on R2 network can already access everything on R1 network. So you are a little backwards here. You could swap it around and problem solved with better security. But you’d have to bypass web filters for the “adult” network.